# Are two C void pointers with the same data different memory objects?

Tags: c, pointers

For example:

```
void *p1 = someStringPointer;
void *p2 = p1;
```

Although these are two unique pointers, given that they both point to the same value, are they still different memory objects?

Comment: The variables themselves are different objects. Compare e.g. `&p1` with `&p2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you print the address of `p1` and `p2`

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) &p1);
printf("%p\n", (void *) &p2);
```

They have different addresses, so yes they are different memory objects.

Comment: Printing 2 `void*` and seeing different text,  is not in itself, sufficient to know the 2 `void*` point to different locations.  Although a textual difference is sufficient with a flat memory model, use `printf("%d\n", &p1 == &p2);` to assess equivalence.  In this case, the result is 0 as objects `p1, p2` are distinct and so is their addresses.

Comment: @chux could you make some example where the printed addresses are the same, but `&p1 != &p2`?

Comment: @Giovanni: chux wrote that different results for `%p` could still be the same location, not that same results could be different locations. The C standard does not dictate the representations of pointers, and one location could be represented in different ways, but any one representation must represent one location.

Answer (score 3):

`p1` and `p2` locate on two different address on memory( in this case is stack area) but they contain the same value, their value is `someStringPointer`.